# How to clear existing figure in excel using matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, graph

I have an excel that is connected to matlab through active server. 
I am generating a graph via matlab and export it to excel. However, I need to clear the existing graphs first so it won't overwrite and make a stacked of graphs.

My idea is to find the existing graph first, and clear it. But, so far, I still don't know how to do it.

Anyone knows? I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you so much!

Elizabeth

edit:

this is a matlab script

```
Excel = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); 
filename = 'xxx'
invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Open',filename);
Sheets = Excel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets;
Sheets.Item('Graphs').Activate;
ActiveSheets = Excel.Activesheet;
plotpie(cost,init_stage)
Shapes = ActiveSheets.Shapes;
ActiveSheets.Shapes.AddPicture('location', 0, 1, 400, 325, 345, 230)
```

Comment: Post the code in which you export the graph to MATLAB please

Comment: ActiveSheets.Shapes.AddPicture('location', 0, 1, 400, 325, 345, 230)

Comment: Please *EDIT* your question to add code. Also, please add more complete code. How are you calling that from MATLAB? Is that in your MATLAB script or in a VBA script in the spreadsheet etc...

Comment: I edited the questions. 
I created a routine to plot the pie however, it is basically only loop for my input. The pie generation uses matlab syntax.

Comment: Unless some PHB is forcing you to go this route, **don't** .  Consider any alternative which doesn't use Excel. If forced to use Excel,  export the data to a spreadsheet's specific location and let Excel generate the graph from the raw data.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late reply. 
Actually, it is easier if excel generate the graph however, the number of x and y data are different all the time I run. So, if I make excel generate it, it will be ugly looking graph because some value are not there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Great questions. I can't leave comments so I'll respond here.

Perhaps one of these will work for you.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Delete
ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
```